# Error trying to setup Vault installed on GCP with mysql secret engine plugin

Tags: mysql, database, plugins, google-cloud-platform, hashicorp-vault

I have installed vault on GCP using [terraform template](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vault). 
I have logged on to the vault site *:8200 and successfully created test secret engine and secrets as well from my console and Vault console as well.

A database secret engine also successfully created. But unfortunatelly I'm unable to setup the mysql-database-plugin plugin.

I have tried in several ways to setup the database secret engine:

```
export VAULT_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
export VAULT_ADDR=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8200

vault write -tls-skip-verify database/config/xx plugin_name=mysql-database-plugin connection_url="{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(xx.xx.xx.xx:3306)/" allowed_roles="vault-mysql-role" username="xx" password="xx"
```

But I got:

> Error writing data to database/config/xx: context deadline exceeded

Also tried from Vault console:

```
vault write database/config/mmc plugin_name=mysql-database-plugin connection_url="{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(xx.xx.xx.xx:3306)/" allowed_roles="vault-mysql-role" username="xx" password="xx"
```

Bug I got:

> Error writing to: database/config/mmc.
>   URL: undefined
>   Code: undefined

Also tried the api:

```
curl -k --header "X-Vault-Token: xxxxxxxxxxx" --request POST --data @payload.json https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8200/v1/database/config/mysql
```

Being payload.json:

```
{
  "plugin_name": "mysql-database-plugin",
  "allowed_roles": "readonly",
  "connection_url": "{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(xx.xx.xx.xx:3306)/xx",
  "max_open_connections": 5,
  "max_connection_lifetime": "5s",
  "username": "xx",
  "password": "xx"
}
```

But I got:

> {"errors":["error creating database object: error verifying connection: dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:3306: connect: connection timed out"]}

Does anyone have any clue about what's going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it was a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) issue. Cloud SQL instance has been setup using a public IP, but Vault has been set up using a private IP (bastion host mode), in order to connect a Compute Engine private IP against a Cloud SQL, there are two options:
1) Set up Vault to use a public IP
2) Set up Cloud SQL to use a private IP and custom vpc network, the same Vault uses. Choosed this one for security concerns.